# How do I check if a function is called in a mock method?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, unit-testing, django-models

AuthUser is a class which contains the delete method.
I want to test if the mock delete method calls a function, given the arguments for the method.

```
@mock.patch.object(AuthUser, 'delete')
@mock.patch('oscadmin.common.oscp.deactivate_user')
def test_delete(self, deactivate_user_mock, delete_mock):
    """Test the delete() method in AuthUser"""
    authUserObject = mock.Mock()
    authUserObject.oscp_id = 4

    """If delete_from_oscp = True && oscp_id isset"""
    delete_mock(self, True, authUserObject, mock.Mock())
    self.assertTrue(authUserObject.oscp_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
delete_mock.method_expected_to_be_called.assert_called_once_with(args, kwargs)
```

Comment: delete_mock is the mock method and deactivate_user_mock is the function that I need to check if its called.